# private variable for new PDO connection with datatables

Tags: php, pdo, datatables

I am going to be using a php class that I found for datatables in pdo style.  The top of the file has the following :

```
class TableData {

private $_db;

public function __construct() {

    try {
        $host       = 'localhost';
        $database   = 'my_database';
        $user       = 'myusername';
        $passwd     = 'mypassword';

        $this->_db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $user, $passwd, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    }   
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log("Failed to connect to database: ".$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am not too familiar with classes and writing them.  My question is that for other parts of my site I am already including a php connection file... is it possible to use my default connection below and get rid of the one in the class?  In other words I just want to be able to use $db as I normally would from below rather than creating the private $_db; as shown above.  Possible or not?

```
// db config
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_database    = 'my_database';
$db_user        = 'myusername';
$db_pass        = 'mypassword'; 

//db connection
try {
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_database;charset=utf8", $db_user, $db_pass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
error_log("Failed to connect to database: ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create your PDO class outside and then inject it into your class. That way you only ever have one database connection running.

```
class TableData {
    /** @var \PDO */
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo) {
         $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
}
$class = new TableData($db);
```

Comment: I believe it is already setup that way... I suppose I should have included the entire file.  I want to 'reuse' my plain old connection.php that I require on necessary files though for the same reason - only one connection running.